# Qual técnica usar para manter os campos de um formulário preenchidos ou selecionados após $_POST[]?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, formulário, session

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de imobiliárias e gostaria de perguntar como posso manter os dados de um formulário tais como `inputs`, `selects` e `checkbox` selecionados após dar um `$_POST` no formulário.

Não sei como armazenar estes dados para toda a navegação daquele cliente que está no site mas imagino que deve-se ter alguma coisa relacionada com `sessions`.

**Obrigado pela ajuda.**

Comment: Enviaria com um AJAX para evitar o recarregamento da página e evitando com que fosse mexido nos valores dos elementos HTML.

Comment: Por ajax em um momento ou outro ele vai pra home ou pra página de contato e perde os dados.

Comment: Entendi, então você quer que quando ele volte para a página os dados continuem ali, mesmo fechando o navegador? Caso sim você pode utilizar COOKIES, caso não a utilização de SESSÕES seria a solução.

Answer (score 6):

Pequenos exemplos demonstrando como pode ser feito:

## COOKIE:

> O PHP suporta transparentemente cookies HTTP. Cookies é um mecanismo para guardar dados no navegador remoto e permite o ratreamento ou identificação do retorno de usuários. Você pode criar cookies usando a função setcookie() ou setrawcookie(). Os cookies são uma parte do cabeçalho HTTP, logo setcookie() precisa ser chamada antes que qualquer outro dado seja enviado ao navegador. Esta é a mesma limitação que a função header() tem. Você pode usar as funções de output buferizado para atrasar as impressões do script até que você tenha decidido, ou não, configurar qualquer cookie ou enviar quaisquer cabeçalhos.

**Formulário:**

```
<form action="server.php" method="POST">
    <?php
        if (isset($_COOKIE["valor"])){
            echo '<input type="text" name="valor" value="'.$_COOKIE["valor"].'" />';
        } else {
            echo '<input type="text" name="valor" value="" />';
        }
     ?>
</form>
```

**Servidor:**

```
<?php
   $valor = $_POST['valor'];
   setcookie("valor",$valor);
?>
```

## SESSION:

> Suporte a sessões no PHP consiste de uma maneira de presevar dados através de acessos subsequentes. Isso permite a criação de aplicações mais personalizadas e aumenta o apelo do seu web site.

**Formulário:**

```
<form action="server.php" method="POST">
    <?php
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION["valor"])){
             echo '<input type="text" name="valor" value="'.$_SESSION["valor"].'" />';
        } else {
             echo '<input type="text" name="valor" value="" />';
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

**Servidor:**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $valor = $_POST['valor'];
    $_SESSION['valor'] = $valor;

?>
```

## Diferenças:

> Cookie – As informaçoes ficam gravadas em seu computador, um exemplo disto e um sistema de login de um forum de discussao, se voce entrar nela hoje amanha se voce entrar, voce ainda estará logado.
>
> Session – As informacoes ficam gravadas no servidor. Se voce entra visita um site, e sai, sua sessão termina, ou pode expirar o tempo.

## Referências:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.session.php

https://omundodomario.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/diferenca-entre-cookie-e-session/

Comment: Poderia exemplificar usando input e select para que eu entenda melhor e possa aplicar ao meu projeto? Obrigado

Answer (score 6):

Considero para essa resposta que você quer os valores "selecionados após dar um `$_POST` no formulário", sendo assim não é necessário manter esses dados na sessão, apenas na página submetida pelo formulário.

Não existe uma maneira igual para todos os tipos de campo, então sugiro ter funções para cada tipo, abaixo descrevo exemplos de funções para os tipos texto e select, que podem servir de base para outros tipos.

Utilizei as funções da família do [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php) para montar o HTML, poderia concatenar, por exemplo. Mas vai de cada desenvolvedor.

Para obter os valores do POST utilizei [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php), que faz alguma validações, evitando o uso de `empty()` ou `isset()`.

```php
function inputTextComValor($nome_do_campo) {
  vprintf('<input type="text" name="%s" value="%s"/>', array(
     $nome_do_campo,
     filter_input(INPUT_POST, $nome_do_campo), // equivale a $_POST[$nome_do_campo]
  ));
}

function selectComValor($nome_do_campo, $valores) {
  $selecionado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $nome_do_campo);
  $opcoes = '';
  foreach ($valore as $chave => $valor) {
    $opcoes .= vsprintf('<option value="%s' %s>%s</option>, array(
      $chave,
      $chave == $selecionado ? 'selected' : '',
      $valor,
    ));
  }
  printf('<select name="%s">%s</select>', $nome_do_campo, $opcoes);
}
```

Comment: Não sei usar. Ele me gera um outro campo em vez de replicar no mesmo campo. Pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é isso que você quer, mas você pode fazer com que sua página tenha 2 tipos de comportamento, um padrão e um para requisições $_POST, e ao submeter seu formulário, enviar para a própria página.

Eu geralmente utilizo isso para fazer validações, e quando algo é inválido, posso continuar com os dados que o usuário inseriu previamente sem a necessidade de usar AJAX para fazer a validação.

Já se você quer ir para outras páginas e não perder essas informações, é melhor usar cookies.

Acredito que não tenha a necessidade de usar sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para complementar as respostas, em frameworks como `Laravel 4` é possível fazer isso da seguinte forma:

No controller

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput();
```

Na view:

```
{{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name') }}
```

## Explicação

Quando você redireciona chamando o método `withInput`, você está salvando o conteúdo do `$_POST` atual em um `flash` (valores na sessão que só são exibidos uma vez.

O método `Input::old` fica encarregado de capturar esses valores.

Então a minha recomendação é que, se não estiver usando nenhum framework, utilize a sessão para poder salvar esses valores. Faça isso de maneira que você possa criar como flash, para garantir que os valores, depois de utilizados, serão removidos ao mesmo tempo da sessão.